# split web and file server to each dedicated server

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-upload, filesystems

If you want to split web and file server to each dedicated server how can you do that?

When sending a file you need to send it through the web server right? If you need to check the file size, file type or other things before sending and storing the file on the file server?

How is the best way to manage the files on the file server (writing/deleting) from the web server?

## edit

The static files is files uploaded by users.. They have to be validated (mime types etc.) before they are stored.

I need to spread out the traffic load

Comment: what exactly is the file server? and how is it connected to the web server?

Comment: are you talking about static web content? or any file?

Comment: have updated my question

Comment: What makes you think you need to "spread out the traffic load"? A single modern server can saturate even the fattest pipe you're likely to have (e.g. gigabit)

Answer (score 1):

"File server" can mean anything. In some cases it would be something like NFS, CIFS etc, in other cases it might be a SAN or possibly NAS. In the latter case, it means whatever your NAS or SAN vendor thinks it means.

I would question your motivation for doing this. Normally, serving static files over HTTP is something best done from local discs. If you have (say) 10 web servers, it is probably best to sync the static files to each and every server and have them serve it from local storage (after all, storage is cheap, right?).

In the case where you have dynamic storage of files, then storing them centrally may make sense, but it depends on exactly what your use-case is whether it's a good idea. In that case, you *could* store them on a "file server" (e.g. NFS, CIFS) and access them from your pool of web servers (but of course, this introduces a single point of failure, which defeats part of the reason to have multiple servers).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a centralized file storage, I would suggest using NFS. You "mount" your file server on the webserver via NFS, and the web server "thinks" the files are local. You can read and write the files just as if they were local.